# Can't change the size of string inside a numpy array

Tags: python, string, numpy, replace

I am having a problem changing the size of a string stored in a NumPy array. e.g. I have stored the path of images in an array and I was replacing the ".png" at the end with "*something*.png" using the "replace" function. But what happens is the operation only keeps the new string up to the original length of string, anything extra is not added.

1. E:\Thesis
   Data\2018-weedMap-dataset-release\Tiles\RedEdge\000\groundtruth\000_frame0000.png
2. E:\Thesis
   Data\2018-weedMap-dataset-release\Tiles\RedEdge\000\groundtruth\000_frame0000_und

1: Original String 2: replaced String

As one can see in above strings , I was replacing ".png" with "_underground.png" but it only kept "_und" which equals the length of string I was replacing i.e ".png".

Comment: please don't post images of text. It is not searchable, and not readable by screen readers for the visually impaired.

Comment: The answer might depend on *how* you are trying to do this, which have forgotten to share.

Comment: strings in numpy arrays have a maximum size determined by the array's `dtype`.  Looks like this array  is 'U4'

Comment: dtype is <U91 @hpaulj

Answer (score 0):

So your sample string(s) is 91 char long, consistent with the '<U91' dtype.  You can't increase that without making a new array with a longer dtype.

```
In [11]: ''' 1. E:\Thesis
    ...:     Data\2018-weedMap-dataset-release\Tiles\RedEdge\000\groundtruth\000_frame0000.
    ...: png '''
Out[11]: ' 1. E:\\Thesis\n    Data\x818-weedMap-dataset-release\\Tiles\\RedEdge\x00\\groundtruth\x00_frame0000.png '
In [12]: len(_)
Out[12]: 91
```